# DataGridView does not display DataTable

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview, datatable, system.data.sqlite

I've got the following code which I think ought to be binding a DataTable to a DataGridView, but the DataGridView shows up empty.  The DataTable definately has rows, so I assume that I am binding the DataSource incorrectly some how.  Does anyone see what is wrong with this:

```
DataBase db = new DataBase(re.OutputDir+"\\Matches.db");
MatchDBReader reader = new MatchDBReader(db.NewConnection());

BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = reader.GetDataTable();

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource.DataSource;
```

- The first line simply gets a handle to the DB that I'm pulling data from.
- The next line is a provides a class for reading from that same db - in particular it exposes the GetDataTable method with returns the data table that I intend to put into the DataGridView.
- The next line is uninteresting...
- The 4th line attempts to grab the DataTable - QuickWatch indicates that this is working...
- The final line is where I assume i've screwed up...my understanding is that this binds the DataTable to the DataGridView GUI, but nothing shows up.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of this worked for me, though it all seemed like good advice.  What I ended up doing was the biggest, worst hack on earth.  What I was hoping to accomplish was simply to load a DB table from a SQLite db and present it (read only, with sortable columns) in the DataGridView.  The actual DB would be programmatically specified at runtime.  I defined the DataSet by adding a DataGridView to the form and used the Wizards to statically define the DB connection string.  Then I went into the Settings.Designer.cs file and added a `set` accessor to the DB Connection string property:

```
namespace FormatDetector.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "9.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("data source=E:\\workspace\\Test\\Matches.db;useutf16encoding=True")]
        public string MatchesConnectionString {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["MatchesConnectionString"]));
            }
            set
            {
                (this["MatchesConnectionString"]) = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a klugey hack, but it works.  Suggestions about how to clean this mess up are more than welcome.

brian

Answer (score 2):

Try binding the DataGridView directly to the BindingSource, and not the BindingSource's DataSource:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach your BindingSource to your grid, before you get the data table.

Try switching the last two lines of code:

```
DataBase db = new DataBase(re.OutputDir+"\\Matches.db");
MatchDBReader reader = new MatchDBReader(db.NewConnection());
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource.DataSource;
bindingSource.DataSource = reader.GetDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with above solutions also fix the "bindingSource" datamember property. like:

```
bindingSource.DataMember = yourDataSet.DataTable;
```

I had the same problem with sql database and datagrid view. After a great deal of trouble I found out that I've forgot to set dataMember property of my binding source.

best of luck.

Comment: that's actually what im doing with this line here: 

bindingSource.DataSource = reader.GetDataTable();

Comment: you are setting the datasoure property of bindingSource... not the DataMember property of your datasource... there is difference.

Comment: I'm aware this in an old Q but stumbled upon it. I get an error when trying your suggestion Asad, VS complains "Value of type System.Data.DataTable cannot be converted to String"

Comment: @Dan try .ToString() method of like  
  bindingSource.DataMember = yourDataSet.DataTable.toString();

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridView` takes a `DataTable` as a basis. The `DataTable` Columns save their Type as a property.

If this type is an Interface all you would see are empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me  (put in Form_Load):

```
this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Apparently it's the only way because AutoGenerateColumns isn't listed anywhere on the grid's property sheet.