# DataGridView not showing columns from DataTable C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, datagridview, datatable

My GUI has a datagridview in Form1 and is supposed to be populated by data from a datatable that lives in a separate class. I have set up the binding source and data source, but when I run my GUI, the datagridview is blank and does not show the columns from my datatable. At this point I'm not storing any data for the rows, I just want to make sure my column headers get displayed.

I have looked at all the following links and nothing has helped so far:

[DataGridView not showing Columns/Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856252/datagridview-not-showing-columns-data)

[DataGridView not showing my columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265702/datagridview-not-showing-my-columns)

[how to bind datatable to datagridview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

[DataGridView does not display DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900112/datagridview-does-not-display-datatable)

Here's my code

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataTable dataTable = LightSensor.dtOptical;
    DGV.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

LightSensor.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static DataTable dtOptical = new DataTable();
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

private void OpticalDataSetup()
{
    dtOptical.Columns.Add("Sequence");
    dtOptical.Columns.Add("Date");
    dtOptical.Columns.Add("Time");
}
private void OpticalDataRows()
{
    DataRow row = dtOptical.NewRow();

    row = dtOptical.NewRow();
    row["Sequence"] = MeasSeq;
    row["Date"] = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
    row["Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

    dtOptical.Rows.Add(row);
    bindingSource.DataSource = dtOptical;
}
```

Comment: So, is AutoGenerateColumns on?

Comment: @TaW I tried setting AutoGenerateColumns to both true and false. Neither had an impact on the dgv.

Comment: This should be easy to debug.  Put a stop on the `DataTable dataTable = LightSensor.dtOptical;` line and when you reach it, step through the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: Please show the class header!

Comment: @LarsTech Tried that...program just steps through to DGV.DataSource then to Application.Run(new Form1()) in Program.cs then goes to my GUI window.

Comment: @TaW I updated the code above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a Constructor in your LightSensor class that calls **OpticalDataSetup** and 
**OpticalDataRows** :

```
public LightSensor(){
 OpticalDataSetup();
 OpticalDataRows();
}
```

then initialize LightSensor after InitializeComponent();

```
LightSensor ls = new LightSensor();
```

Comment: Either that ot make all parts static; then no instance is needed.. If the class is statis it should be `static  LightSensor() {..` But the constructor is needed in any case.

Comment: That fixed it! I was just missing the call for OpticalDataSetup(). Instead of your approach, I just added LightSensor.OpticalDataSetup(); in my Form1 after InitializeComponent();